# How to smartly remove floating point errors from imported data in R

Tags: r, floating-point, rounding-error

I'm working in R where I import data from a database. The database provides numbers with floating point rounding errors. For example, 2 values I'm working with are Limit1 <- 0.0280000008642673 and Limit2 <- 0.259999990463257, for example. The database doesn't know any better, I can't force it to give me better data. It's not my database and there's nothing I can do about it there.

Limit1 should be rounded to 3 decimals, and Limit2 to 2 decimals. While I can certainly use the round function, I'm hoping there is an existing function or maybe something someone has written to intelligently convert these to the proper decimals without me having to round them 1 by 1, manually, hardcoded.

I've been dreaming up a kloogy way to count consecutive 9's or 0's and find out the number of significant decimal digits from that information, assuming that none of the true values contain "000" or "999". However, I feel like I can't be the only person who has run into this. There has to be a better way.

Thanks

Comment: The `zapsmall()` function is included to take care of floating point errors, but it doesn't work for these numbers.  What if you just used `round(x,7)` on both of them?

Comment: Perhaps, see, also `?signif`? E.g. `as.character(c(Limit1, Limit2)); as.character(signif(c(Limit1, Limit2)))` seems to work for your example.

Comment: I don't understand why you can't use these numbers as they are.

Comment: For calculation they're fine, but I need to show these numbers on a legend for some charts I'm plotting.

Interestingly, if I ask R to show me those values in the console, it rounds them perfectly for viewing - does it use a function I can access to preserve those rounded values?

Comment: You are looking for functions like `print.default` (`print` is called implicitly for console output and you can set some global `options`), `format`, `sprintf`, `formatC`, ...

Answer (score 1):

Based on your clarification in the comments you need something like this:

```
Limits <- c(0.0280000008642673, 0.259999990463257)
plot(1)
legend("topright", legend = prettyNum(Limits), fill = 1:2)
```

[image: resulting plot]

I really don't see a reason to change the actual numbers if you are only concerned about formatting.